# User Permissions on custom post type

Tags: users, user-roles, permissions

what is the best practice approach for the following scenario:

We have a main page and need user control for our departments of our sports club. For this we registered a custom post type (departments). The hierarchy looks like this:

```
enter I. Index
         1. About us
         2. News
         3. Departments (departments-archive.php – custom post type)
            a.) Department A (single-archive.php - custom post type)
               aa.) News of department A
               bb.) Events of department A
            b.) Department B here
               aa.) News of department B
               bb.) Events of department B
```

For every department there will be a user, which should be able to make changes only on its own department site and its child pages. Beside that the user should be able to write posts, related to its department and to upload media files (images).

Is there a (free) plugin, which can handle this for me, can this be done with php snippets in my child themes functions.php or are multisites the way to go? I know, there are many ways, I just want to know which one is the most reliable and user friendly way.

Comment: I don't know about free plugins for this purpose, but definitely can be done in a few dozens of lines of php in you theme functions.
What I'd do, create a custom field for every user, where you can set their permissions.
Then you have to create a function, that checks the current post type and compares it to the current user's permission field. If identical, proceed, else bail.
Then you have to find a Wordpress hook that's fired when a user edits/creates a post, and use 'add_action' to hook your function to the action.

Comment: This is a good starting point. I am not very good in php up to now, but I will have a look. Can't imagine that I am the first person, who wants to add such a functionality. If anyone can provide me a starting point on this php solution or can direct me to another good approach, I'd be happy. Thanks @galingong